# Loop that will execute as many times as user directs

Tags: java

Write a program to calculate the current grade based on the CSE 1341 syllabus. The program should prompt the user for their first and last name. It will then pass those names as Strings to the second method of the CSE1341Grade class. The name of the second method will be calcGrade. This method will prompt the user for the count of exam scores, count of quiz scores, and count of lab scores to entered by the user.

It will then utilize repetition structure to prompt for exam grades, quiz grades and lab grades based on the previous counts entered. For example, if the user entered count of exam scores to be 2; then the program will loop 2 times to input the two exam grades; and similarly for the count of quiz and count lab grades.

Assume you have a 100% attendance record and you will get all 5% of the attendance grade.
Use the syllabus to determine the weights of each of the categories such as the exams, quizzes and labs. Add 5% to the total score since you had perfect attendance.
Assume: all exams, labs and quiz scores are out of 100 points.
Sample Run:
￼

> java CSE1341Grade
>
> First name: James
>
> Last name: Bond
>
> How many exam grades do you have? 1
>
> How many quiz grades do you have? 2
>
> How many lab grades do you have? 2
>
> Enter exam 1 score: 90
>
> Enter quiz 1 score: 80
>
> Enter quiz 2 score: 80
>
> Enter lab 1 score: 90
>
> Enter lab 2 score: 90
>
> Total Score: 84.55
>
> James Bond your grade is a: B

^^That is my homework assignment, and this is what I have done so far

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CSE1341Grade
{
    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        //set up Scanner for user input, prompt for first name, define variable, and print      response
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("First name: ");
        String first = s.nextLine();
        System.out.printf(" %s\n", first);

        //prompt user for last name, define variable, and print response
        System.out.print("Last name: ");
        String last = s.nextLine();
        System.out.printf(" %s\n", last);
    }

    public static void calcGrade(String first, String last)
    { 
        //prompt user for number of exam grades, define exam variable, print response
        System.out.print("How many exam grades do you have? ");
        String exam = s.nextLine();
        System.out.printf(" %s\n", exam);

        //prompt user for number of quiz grades, define quiz variable, print response
        System.out.print("How many quiz grades do you have? ");
        String quiz = s.nextLine();
        System.out.printf(" %s\n", quiz);

        //prompt user for number of lab grades, define lab variable, print response
        System.out.print("How many lab grades do you have? ");
        String lab = s.nextLine();
        System.out.printf(" %s\n", lab);

        while (exam != -1)
        {
            System.out.print("Enter " exam 1 " score: ", ++exam)



        //define variables for computations
        int score = 0;
        int grade = 0;

        //if statement to determine the final letter grade
        if(score >= 90 && score <=100){
            grade = 'A'; }
        else if(score >=80 && score < 90){
            grade = 'B'; }
        else if(score >= 70 && score < 80){
            grade = 'C'; }
        else if(score >=60 && score < 70){
            grade = 'D'; }
        else {
            grade = 'F'; }
    }
}
```

My problem is figuring out how to create a loop that will prompt the user for however many exam grades needed.

Comment: +1 for asking the homework question the way it should be on SO

Comment: Double that +1 for correct way to ask hw q's

Comment: Convert the string parameters to an int, then use a "for" loop with the int values as the limit.

Comment: A proper homework question -- and I'm out of votes for today...

Comment: Hint: Create an array with size equal to number of exam grades and then run a loop taking input from the user and putting that into the array

Comment: Instead of using -1 (which would be the escape) prompt the user for the amount of exams using Scanner.nextInt and then you can use a counter, a for loop would be better if you know the amount of times to do something.

Comment: `System.out.print("Enter "   exam 1   " score: ", ++exam)`  add + to concatenate strings or don't open the quotes if that is not a concatenation.  `System.out.print("Enter exam " + count +  " score: ", ++exam)` Maybe you want something like that..

Comment: `String exam = s.nextLine();` that could be `int examsCount = s.nextInt()` OR you can use `int examsCount=Integer.parseInt(exam)` assuming you will only introduce integers.

Comment: you can almost always tell it's a student when you see the curly braces {'s on the next line...

Comment: `while (exam != -1)` You should not use `==` nor `!=` when comparing strings to a value, Strings should be compared using `equals` method instead, in your case something like: `while(!"-1".equals(exam))`

Comment: `++exam` You cannot use that if your exam variable is a String, if you wanted to do that and also the !=1 then you need an integer, change your nextLine call for a nextInt

Comment: Your `Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);` is defined inside the `main` method. You cannot use it inside the calcGrade method. You have to either declare a global variable (outside the main method but inside your class) or declare another one for the calcGrade method. If you declare a global one, it might be static since you are running your code in a static context.

Comment: yes, use Scanner.nextInt() instead of Scanner.nextLine() to read in an integer only (it won't move on until the user enters a number, which is good for validation)

Answer (score 1):

I have performed few changes to your code based in the comments ..

Here you can see the diff

http://www.mergely.com/LIckVifT/

Note: It still does not finish your homework :-)

Update: Since the index in the foor loop does not really matters you could use it as this:

```
 for (int i = 1; i <= examsCount; i++) {
      // using i+1 to print starting from 1 instead of 0
      System.out.print("Enter " + i + " score: ");
```

instead of

```
for (int i = 0; i < examsCount; i++) {
      // using i+1 to print starting from 1 instead of 0
      System.out.print("Enter " + (i + 1) + " score: ");
```

Answer (score 0):

I like to do a loop and continue to ask the user for input until I get the result I want:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    boolean shouldContinue = true;

    while(shouldContinue) {

        // do program logic

        System.out.print("Should we continue? [Y or N] >> ");

        if (input.nextLine().equalsIgnoreCase("N")) {

            shouldContinue = false;

        }

    }

}
```

This is a relatively "structured" way to do an interaction loop and continue running a program over and over so long as the user wants.

`-- UPDATE --`

To do a number of iterations that you know ahead of time, simply pipe that into your counter for the loop:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Number of grades to enter [number] : ");

    int numberOfTimesToIterate = input.nextInt();

    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfTimesToIterate; i++) {

        // do stuff here

    }

}
```

Comment: He did that already using -1 instead of Y/N. He needs a loop for fixed amount of exams.

Answer (score 0):

Pseudo-code:

```
function(int n) {
    for (i = n, i > 0, i--) {
        \\prompt user
    }
}
```

That should give you the general idea of how to do it, namely taking the amount, and subtracting 1 from it until you reach 0, each time getting the data and doing what it needs to do with it. Don't forget to make sure that `n` never equals less than zero (invalid), and that `n` is an integer. Otherwise, it is desirable that you have the function simply prompt the user for an amount, then pass that amount to the function that actually uses it. Alternatively, create a function which iterates `n` times and calls a function passed to it as an argument that many times (much harder to correctly do).

Comment: @SnakeDoc: Hmm, I have no clue why I decided to do a for loop that counts downwards, but it's basically the same solution.

Comment: lol, same difference. except you appear to be in javascript land instead of java land ;-P

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work for you.

```
System.out.println("Please enter the number of exam grades you want to enter");
int grade_count = s.nextInt();
int [] grades = new int[grade_count];

for(int i =0; i<grade_count; i++){
System.out.println("Enter grade for "+i+1 +"Exam");
grades[i] = s.nextInt();
}
```